# I do not want a trailing comma after last element xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

In my schema I have AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3 and AddressLine4. When address is added to each AddressLine a comma is inserted to separate the AddressLines. However if only AddressLine1 and AddressLine2 have address, then there should not be a comma after the AddressLine2 because there is nothing else after it.
My output is showing a trailing comma after AddressLine2 (Sydney Australia 123456A,) even though it should not.
Output
472 Case Ave, Apt 2, Saint Paul, MN, 55106; 123 Beautiful Ocean, Sydney Australia 123456A,

**Xml code**

```
<Address InternalAddressID="1618212014" Type="Foreign">
    <Location Word="OTHER">Other</Location>
    <AddressLine1>123 Beautiful Ocean</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>Sydney Australia 123456A</AddressLine2>
    <Foreign>true</Foreign>
</Address>
```

**Xslt code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Addresses/Address">
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">
<xsl:if test="AddressLine1">
<xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="AddressLine2">
<xsl:value-of select="AddressLine2"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="AddressLine3">
<xsl:value-of select="AddressLine3"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="AddressLine4">
<xsl:value-of select="AddressLine4"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please say whether you want an XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you change your strategy to something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Address">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Or, on the off-chance you're using **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:template match="Address">
    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4" separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
<xsl:for-each select="AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```