# How to correctly cocatenate two datafields with comma between?

Tags: xslt, concatenation

I have following two Datafields in my XML:

```
 <datafield tag="036C">
<subfield code="a">Ėkonomičeskaja politika Rossii v uslovijach globalʹnoj turbulentnosti</subfield>
<subfield code="y">meždunarodnyj finansovo-ėkonomičeskij forum - 2014 (24-26 nojabrja, Moskva)</subfield>
<subfield code="c">Finansovyj universitet pri pravitelʹstve Rossijskoj Federacii</subfield>
<subfield code="l">tom 3</subfield></datafield>

<datafield tag="036C" occurrence="01">
<subfield code="a">Materialy zasedanij kruglych stolov</subfield>
<subfield code="l">Čast 2</subfield>
</datafield>
```

I tried to concatenate them with comma between in XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="pica036C"
                        select="recordData/record/datafield[@tag='036C']" />

    <xsl:variable name="titleFrom036C">

                          <xsl:for-each select="$pica036C">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(datafield[@tag='036c'][1], ', ', datafield[@tag='036c'][2])" />    
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

The problem is that I get too much commas. The first one is always before the first datafield 036c (, Ėkonomičeskaja). It should be deleted. The second one is between two datafields- that is right. How to delete the first comma?

Actual:
, Ėkonomičeskaja politika Rossii v uslovijach globalʹnoj turbulentnosti : meždunarodnyj finansovo-ėkonomičeskij forum - 2014 (24-26 nojabrja, Moskva) ; tom 3, Materialy zasedanij kruglych stolov ; Čast 2

Have to be (first comma is deleted, comma after "tom 3" remains ):
Ėkonomičeskaja politika Rossii v uslovijach globalʹnoj turbulentnosti : meždunarodnyj finansovo-ėkonomičeskij forum - 2014 (24-26 nojabrja, Moskva) ; tom 3, Materialy zasedanij kruglych stolov ; Čast 2

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28774515/3016153 If not, please edit your question and post the exact result you want to get.

Comment: This doesn't help. In my example comma doesn't appear after the last element. But it appears before the first one which is not right

Comment: It seems like you may want to accommodate more than two `<datafield>` elements with the same tag.  Is that the case?  Because if you can rely on there always being exactly two then this is easier.

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko The direction is not important. The principle is the same. Use `[1`] instead of `last()`, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking like a procedural programmer.  Do not use `xsl:for-each` where XSL's natural iterative processing of the members of a node set suffices.  And if you want special handling (such as no leading comma) in the transformation of a given node, then consider giving it its own template.

Here's a fairly simple way you could apply those principles to achieve what you seem to want (I had to guess a bit at some of the details you omitted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <!-- a different set of datafields could be selected instead by applying
         this template with a different value for this parameter: -->
    <xsl:param name="tag" select="'036C'"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="datafield[@tag=$tag][1]"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="datafield[@tag=$tag][position() > 1]" mode="concat" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="datafield" mode="concat">
    <!-- prepend a ", " to the default transformation of this element -->
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="datafield">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code='a']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code='y']">
      <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="' : '"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subfield[@code='l']">
      <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="' ; '"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="subfield">
    <xsl:param name="delim"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$delim"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

What actually contains `pica036C` variable in your code?
It is an array containing 2 items, taken from both `datafield` tags.

And now, what actually contains the first item:

- A text node - spaces and *\n* between opening *datafield* tag
  and the first opening *subfield* tag.
- The first *subfield* tag.
- Another text node - spaces and *\n* between first closing *subfield*
  tag and second opening *subfield* tag.
- And so on.

So `datafield[@tag='036c'][1]` refers to the node containing only "white" 
chars. The next item to concatenate is `', '` and this is what you see
as the "initial" comma.

Remember also, that inside `<xsl:for-each select="$pica036C">` loop
`.` refers to the current element in `pica036C` array.

So if you want to get `subfield`, write `subfield`, without names of
parent nodes, which exist only in the source document, but not in `pica036C`.

My suggestion:

1. Create `pica036C` variable this way:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="pica036C" as="text()*">
     <xsl:for-each select="recordData/record/datafield[@tag='036C']">
       <xsl:value-of select="string-join(subfield, '&#xA;')"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>
   ```

   You get also an array with 2 items, each containing joined subfields
   from respective datafield, but **without** whitespace text nodes between
   them.

   The 2nd argument of `string-join`, instead of `&#xA;` (a newline)
   can be a space (what is better for your final result).
2. Create `titleFrom036C` this way:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="titleFrom036C" select=
       "concat($pica036C[1], ',&#xA;', $pica036C[2])" />
   ```

   Then, when you use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$titleFrom036C"/>`
   you will get:

   - Full title of the first publication.
   - A comma and newline.
   - Full title of the second publication.